# OpenCV on BeagleBoard-xM

Tags: opencv, beagleboard

I am working on BeagleBoard-xM with an Angstrom image built with the online Narcissus image builder (open embedded) for an OpenCV application.  I included OpenCV in the root file system, but when I try to compile a simple OpenCV program, I get an error saying `library highgui, cxcore not found`.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of OpenCV with 2.2 they split those libs into individual modules.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20Change%20Logs

Answer (score 1):

http://movidius.tumblr.com/

OPENCV ON BEAGLEBOARD XM

The standard BeagleBoard android build runs on the xM is very spartan and it would require a lot of effort to get OpenCV up and running.

I therefore chose Ubuntu 10.10 as an alternative.

It is much more straightforward to install and install the required features such as cmake and gcc required to compile directly on the xM.

One thing is to choose a webcam which will work with cheese under Ubuntu. Eventually I found a €20 Logitech C200 webcam which does.

You need to implement this fix to get OpenCV to build for the ARM target under Ubuntu
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/77273

It means commenting the line 51 in sift.cpp
//#define ARM_NO_SIFT

Following this OpenCV will build fine under Ubuntu for the BeagleBoard xM.

In many cases there appear to be problems for the ARM to keep up with the JPEG stream from webcams so you'll need to run cmake with the -DWITH_JPEG=OFF option.

This has the added benefit of upping the frame-rate slightly as you don't need to decode JPEG on the ARM.

To install you will need to give yourself root privileges

> sudo passwd root

You can then make install OpenCV and you’re ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the files /usr/lib/libhighgui.so.2.1, /usr/lib/libcxcore.so.2.1? If not, try

```
opkg install libhighgui2.1
opkg install libcxcore2.1
```

Alternatively, try searching for the libs at http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/